# Draw/Doodle/Annotate an existing image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have been searching online for examples/information on how to create an app that will allow the user to draw (or doodle) on an existing image. Much like the features available in that of Snapchat and Markup. 
I have found multiple examples of a drawing app which allows the user to freely draw whatever they want across a blank canvas, but I am struggling to find information how to enable the drawing to be over an existing image such as a photo. 
The overall aim is to be able to draw on the image then save the annotated image.

Any help or guidance where to start with this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!